# Removing Markers with OnClick in <option>

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a dropdown menu with two categories. When category #1 is selected, the markers drop fine, but when category #2 is selected, the markers do not drop if I have `markers.setMap(null)` in the function. The markers from category #1 should remove when category #2 is selected. I am pushing the markers to a global array so I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

```
function dropMarkers2() {
    markers.setMap(null); // This line seems to be the issue
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var data = markersList2[i];
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latLng[0], data.latLng[1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
        markers2.push(marker);

        i++;
        if (i == markersList2.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 150);
}
```

My JSFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/g7uhond8/

**EDIT:** I've worked on two versions, but still haven't solved the problem.

In this JSFiddle, the markers won't stop dropping. Something wrong with my for loop. http://jsfiddle.net/k9eomk5f

In this JSFiddle, I am able to remove markers, but the markers drop at the same location. They don't iterate if I use `markerList`, but do when I use `neighborhoods`: http://jsfiddle.net/zeyn30tm

Why is that? `markerList` is a list and `neighborhoods` is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`markers` is an array(which doesn't have a method `setMap`)

You must iterate over this array and call the method `setMap` for each item(marker).

Comment: Should I use a `for` loop?

Comment: Now the markers won't stop dropping. Something wrong with my `for` loop. http://jsfiddle.net/k9eomk5f/

Comment: In this version, I am able to remove markers, but the markers drop at the same location. They don't iterate if I use `markerList`, but do when I use `neighborhoods`. This is based off an example from Google Maps documentation: http://jsfiddle.net/zeyn30tm/

Comment: @kolor: I guess that's what you want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/z3mkpoLa/ (it uses MVCObject like the example linked in the comment above)

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your JSFiddle, the problem is the way `dropMarkers` and `dropMarkers2` is called. In your HTML, you have:

```
<select>
  <option onclick="dropMarkers();">Category #1</option>
  <option onclick="dropMarkers2();">Category #2</option>
</select>
```

`Option`elements don't have an `onclick` method. What you need to do is attach a function to the `select` element's `onchange` method:

```
<select onchange="dropMarkers(this)">
  <option value="1">Category #1</option>
  <option value="2">Category #2</option>
</select>
```

This way, whenever an option is selected, `dropMarkers` is called, passing in the `select` element as its only argument (referred to by `this`). `dropMarkers` itself will have to be refactored to accept the new argument and process it.

The additional advantage of this solution (besides merely working :)) is that you can get rid of the duplication in all your code. You won't *need* the `dropMarkers2` function. You simply check what the `value` of the `select` element is in your function. (Note that we changed the `option` elements to have `value` attributes above.)

```
function dropMarkers(target) {
  var option = target.value; // the `value` attribute of the `select` element passed in
  if (option == 1) {
    // drop the markers in set 1
  } else if (option == 2) {
    // drop the markers in set 2
  //  ...
}
```

It will take refactoring your code, but it can come out on the other end much cleaner. There are a lot of things that could go into that, but for now, the takeaway point is that you call a function by attaching to the `select` element, and that the `select` element has an attribute called `value`, which is equal to the `value` attribute of whatever `option` element is selected. By passing in the `select` element to the function, you can then refer to the `value` of the element inside the function.

If you understand that, you will be able to fix your problem.